# How do I prevent 18 screensaver windows from opening?

Tags: boot, kubuntu, screensaver, autostart, startup-applications

When I login to KDE, ~18 `kdeasciiquarium.kss` processes run, each in a separate window. That's my screensaver, but why is it starting in a window, and why do 18 of them run?

This began happening after upgrading from Kubuntu 13.04 to 13.10 .

[image]

Comment: KDE bug - more: http://www.kubuntuforums.net/showthread.php?63503-kblankscrn-kss and

Comment: Voted off topic and closed, yet still a useful question (I'm experiencing the same problem) and a useful answer (it solved the problem). I don't understand the SE community sometimes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

KDE System Settings > Startup and Shutdown > Session Management - exclude the screen savers from the restored.

[image]